# Amazon Mechanical Turk API - Using GetReviewableHITs to get all reviewable HITs regardless of HITTypeId

Tags: mechanicalturk

**Current Result:** Calling GetReviewableHITs without HITTypeId returns all HITs of the requester even if status is **not** equal to Reviewable. (seems to become analogous to the SearchHits method)

**Desired Result:** Calling GetReviewableHITs without HITTypeId returns all HITs of the requester where the status of each HIT **is equal** to Reviewable.

**At the end of the day, I'm simply looking for an efficient means to get all of my HITs that are in the Reviewable state without having to supply a HITTypeId.**

The GetReviewableHITs API specifies that that if HITTypeId is "not specified, all of the Requester's HITs are considered for the query." After testing, indeed all HITs are returned even with status not equal to Reviewable or Reviewing. So this appears to be by design of the API. So I'm looking for other ideas.

For example, do I indeed have to return all the HITs and iterate through each to find the reviewable ones? Without thousands of HITs this doesn't scale well. Or do I need to maintain my own state for the HITTypeIds? Seems I can't find an API to return me them so this becomes a lot of overhead to have to maintain my own database just for this one API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default call to `GetReviewableHITs` from the SDK I'm using (.NET) has a ["Minimal ResponseGroup"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMturkAPI/ApiReference_CommonParametersArticle.html#response-groups) meaning that the HITs returned did not have `Status` field. A later call to `GetHIT` with a detailed "ResponseGroup" allowed me to see that in fact all the status fields of the HITs returned were in the Reviewable state.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer to this question so others can see it has been addressed.

Comment: Tried doing it right away but was notified I had to wait 2 days.